# Union multiple number of lists in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, extension-methods

I am looking for a elegant solution for the following situation:

I have a class that contains a List like

```
class MyClass{ 
...
 public List<SomeOtherClass> SomeOtherClassList {get; set;}
...
}
```

A third class called `Model` holds a `List<Myclass>` which is the one I am operating on from extern.

Now I would like to extend the Model class with a method that returns all unique SomeOtherClass instances over all MyClass instances.

I know that there is the `Union()` method and with a foreach loop I could solve this issue easily, which I actually did. However, since I am new to all the C#3+ features I am curious how this could be achieved more elegantly, with or without Linq.

I have found an approach, that seems rather clumsy to me, but it works:

```
        List<SomeOtherClass> ret = new List<SomeOtherClass>();
        MyClassList.Select(b => b.SomeOtherClasses).ToList().ForEach(l => ret = ret.Union(l).ToList()); 
        return ret;
```

Note: The `b.SomeotherClasses` property returns a `List<SomeOtherClasses>`.

This code is far away from being perfect and some questions arise from the fact that I have to figure out what is good style for working with C#3 and what not. So, I made a little list with thoughts about that snippet, which I would be glad to get a few comments about. Apart from that I'd be glad to hear some comments how to improve this code any further.

- The temporary list `ret` would have been part of an approach in C#2 maybe, but is it correct that I should be able to resign this list with using method chaining instead? Or am I missing the point?
- Is it really required to use the intermediate `ToList()` method? All I want is to perform a further action each member of a selection.
- What is the cost of those ToList() operations? Are they good style? Necessary?

Thanks.

Comment: What does unique mean here? I mean, do you store multiple references to the same object in your `List<SomeOtherClass>`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are looking for `SelectMany()` + `Distinct()` :

```
List<SomeOtherClass> ret =  MyClassList.SelectMany( x => x.SomeOtherClasses)
                                       .Distinct()
                                       .ToList();
```

`SelectMany()` will flatten the "list of lists" into one list, then you can just pick out the distinct entries in this enumeration instead of using union between individual sub-lists.

In general you will want to avoid side effects with Linq, your original approach is kind of abusing this my modifying `ret` which is not part of the query.

`ToList()` is required since each standard query operator returns a new enumeration and does not modify the existing enumeration, hence you have to convert the final enumeration result back to a list. The cost of `ToList()` is a full iteration of the enumeration which, in most cases, is negligible. Of course if your class could use an `IEnumerable<SomeOtherClass>` instead, you do not have to convert to a list at all.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for.
It'll solve the problem and it also removes the intermediate .ToList() step. Thanks, I have learned something today. Friday is good. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx). Something like this should generate your "flat" list:

```
MyClassList.SelectMany(b => b.SomeOtherClasses)
```

It will return a `IEnumerable<SomeOtherClass>` which you can filter/process further.