# Simplest way to form a union of two lists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, union

What is the easiest way to compare the elements of two lists say A and B with one another, and add the elements which are present in B to A only if they are not present in A?

To illustrate,
Take list A = {1,2,3}
list B = {3,4,5}

So after the operation AUB I want
list A = {1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: If someone is looking for a more dynamic approach watch this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948587/union-multiple-number-of-lists-in-c-sharp

Comment: It should be noted that if you don't need some of the aspects specific to a List (such as maintaining order), [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0) exists to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

If it is a list, you can also use [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method.

```
var listB = new List<int>{3, 4, 5};  
var listA = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

listA.AddRange(listB); // listA now has elements of listB also.
```

If you need new list (and exclude the duplicate), you can use [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx)

```
  var listB = new List<int>{3, 4, 5};  
  var listA = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  var listFinal = listA.Union(listB);
```

If you need new list (and include the duplicate), you can use [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx)

```
  var listB = new List<int>{3, 4, 5};  
  var listA = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  var listFinal = listA.Concat(listB);
```

If you need common items, you can use [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var listB = new List<int>{3, 4, 5};  
var listA = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4};  
var listFinal = listA.Intersect(listB); //3,4
```

Comment: Since this answer pops up first when searching for related operations, it would be nice to add [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation for all the related methods. Thank you very much. keep it up.

Answer (score 31):

The easiest way is to use LINQ's [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) method:

```
var aUb = A.Union(B).ToList();
```

Answer (score 10):

Using LINQ's [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx)

```
Enumerable.Union(ListA,ListB);
```

or

```
ListA.Union(ListB);
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is all you really need to do:

```
var listB = new List<int>{3, 4, 5};
var listA = new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

var listMerged = listA.Union(listB);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is two IEnumerable lists you can't use `AddRange`, but you can use `Concat`.

```
IEnumerable<int> first = new List<int>{1,1,2,3,5};
IEnumerable<int> second = new List<int>{8,13,21,34,55};

var allItems = first.Concat(second);
// 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55
```