# Simplest way to form union of two Lists of objects (Containing Int and string values)

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, for-loop, foreach

I saw a similar question here with a very good solutions:
[Simplest way to form a union of two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505672/simplest-way-to-form-a-union-of-two-lists)

But the problem here is, it works when there is only one parameter in each list (int value). I had this rquirement to combine 5 different lists containing objects of the same class without data redundancy and the final list should be sorted out in ascending order of int value.

Example:

```
Class Company   //data Class
{
int companyNo;
string Name;
}

Class CompanyList : List<Company>
{
  .................
  public CompanyList GetList(int userID)
  {
    .....
  }
}
```

Class company has a pulic method returning list of companies corresponding to a search criteria, let us userID.

```
CompanyList list1 = CompanyList .GetList(userID1);
CompanyList list2 = CompanyList .GetList(userID2);
CompanyList list3 = CompanyList .GetList(userID3);
CompanyList list4 = CompanyList .GetList(userID4);
CompanyList list5 = CompanyList .GetList(userID5);

The solution I implemented is (worked well):

CompanyList _finalList = list1;
*foreach (CompanyList _list in {_list2 ,_list3 ,_list4 ,_list5}) //loop thorugh all other list
{
   foreach (Company item in _list)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i <= _finalList.Count - 1; i++) 
      {
         if (_finalList.Item(i).CompanyNo== item.CompanyNo)
         //***EXIT TAKE NEXT LIST - GO TO *
      }
      if (i == _finalList.Count - 1)  //else check end of first list
      {
        //company no. not yet encountered(new)
        int pos = 0;
        foreach (Company companyInfo in _finalList) //search for position for new company no.
        {
          if (companyInfo.CompanyNo> item.CompanyNo) 
          {
             break;
          } 
          else 
          {
             pos = pos + 1; //increment position
           }
       }
      _finalList.Insert(pos, item); 'Add new item
    }
}

}
```

**the code is converted from VB.Net to C#. Here I could not find the quivalent code piece for this line so replaced it with the concept.

I am not an expert C# programmer and just wondering if there is any better or simpler way to do this?

Data example:

```
Input:
list1[0] = {0,"TCS"};
list1[1] = {1,"Infosys"};
list2[0] = {8,"IBM"};
list3[1] = {1,"Infosys"};
list4[0] = {0,"TCS"};
list5[0] = {9,"Accenture"};
list5[1] = {6,"HCL"};

Output:
finalList[0] = {0,"TCS"};
finalList[1] = {1,"Infosys"};
finalList[2] = {6,"HCL"};
finalList[3] = {8,"IBM"};
finalList[4] = {9,"Accenture"};
```

Regards
Sj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so you have a number of sequences of something, in your case "something" would be `Company`, which doesn't overide `object.Equals` or `object.HashCode`.

So, a new extension like this, might prove useful

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Union(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer,
    params IEnumerable<T>[] others)
{
    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }

    var result = source.Distinct(comparer); 
    foreach(var o in source)
    {
        if (o == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        result = result.Union(o, comparer);
    }

    return result;
}
```

To make this, and other functions that take an `IEqualityComparer` simple to use, you could add this class to your code,

```
public class EqualityComparerImproved<T> : EqaulityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T> equalityComparison;

    private readonly Func<T, int> hashGenerator;

    private EqualityComparerImproved(
             Func<T, T> equalityComparison,
             Func<T, int> hashGenerator)
    {
        this.equalityComparison = equalityComparison;
        this.hashGenerator = hashGenerator;
    }

    public static EqualityComparerImproved<T> Create
             Func<T, T> equalityComparison,
             Func<T, int> hashGenerator)
    {
         if (equalityComparison == null)
         {
             throw new ArgumentNullException("equalityComparison");
         }

         if (hashGenerator == null)
         {
             throw new ArgumentNullException("hashGenerator");
         }

         return new EqualityComparerImproved<T>(
             equalityComparison,
             hashGenerator);
    }

    public override bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return this.equalityComparison(x, y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return this.hashGenerator(obj);
    }
}
```

Once these two, admittedly lengthy, bits of code were in place you could do

```
var output = list1.Union(
    EqualityComparerImproved<Company>.Create(
        (x, y) => x.companyNo == y.companyNo && x.Name == y.Name,
        (obj) =>
            {
                unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
                {
                    int hash = 17;
                    hash = hash * 23 + obj.companyNo;
                    hash = hash * 23 + obj.Name.GetHashCode();
                    return hash;
                }
            },
    list2,
    list3,
    list4,
    list5);
```

or if `companyNo` is a unique key,

```
var output = list1.Union(
    EqualityComparerImproved<Company>.Create(
        (x, y) => x.companyNo == y.companyNo,
        (obj) => obj.companyNo),
    list2,
    list3,
    list4,
    list5);
```

would suffice.

Comment: +1 Nice! I really like the generic IEqualityComparer!  It does make for a bit of a long answer but very complete.  :)

Comment: Thanks Jodrell.. after a bit of extra efforts it worked (as in reality data class is much more complex). +1!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use either GroupBy or Union to remove duplicates... Union makes for a little cleaner linq (I think) but either can work... the downside is that you also need a custom IEqualityComparer in this case since equals on your company objects will return false (since they are different instances)...  An alternative is to have your `Company` class implement IEqualityComparer and just copy the code I have implementing that interface into your `Company` class.

```
// Union gives you a unique list if it knows how to compare the objects properly
var companyEqualityComparer = new CompanyEqualityComparer();
foreach (var companyList in new List<List<Company>>(){list2, list3, list4, list5})
{
    combinedList = combinedList.Union(companyList, companyEqualityComparer);
}
// Order your output list
var finalList = combinedList.OrderBy(c => c.companyNo).ToList();
```

Define your CompanyEqualityComparer...

```
// CompanyEqualityComparer which is needed since your companies are different instances
public class CompanyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Company>
{
    public bool Equals(Company x, Company y)
    {
        return x.companyNo.Equals(y.companyNo);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Company obj)
    {
        return obj.companyNo.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've included an generic `EqualityComparerImproved<T>` class in my answer that has a `Create` method that takes appropriate delegates to return an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Habib's solution, but a bit more concise and complete.

```
int[] userIDs = new[] { userID1, userID2, userID3, userID4, userID5 };

IEnumerable<Company> distinctCompanies =
    from companyList in userIDs.Select(CompanyList.GetList)
    from company in companyList
    group company by company.companyNo into companiesWithSameNo
    select companiesWithSameNo.First();

CompanyList finalList = new CompanyList();
finalList.AddRange(distinctCompanies);
```

You might have a constructor in CompanyList that directly accepts an `IEnumerable<Company>`, too, so you could directly pass `distinctCompanies` there instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like:

```
List<Company> inputList = //Get your input List
List<Company> outputList = inputList.GroupBy(r => r.companyNo)
                                    .Select(grp => new Company
                                        {
                                            companyNo = grp.Key,
                                            Name = grp.First().Name,
                                        })
                                    .OrderBy(r=> r.companyNo)
                                    .ToList();
```