# Loading Data into Listview (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, itemssource

I'm trying to make a duplicate file detector (related question: [Compare adjacent list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010963/compare-adjacent-list-items)).  My general structure is this:

1. Scan directory and load needed details for each file into a DupInfo object
2. Calculate CRCs for any that have a size match with another file
3. Display any with matching size and CRCs (and optionally Base Directories), and allow the users to check which they want to delete (both manually, and using a button like "Check all first duplicates").
4. Delete the selected files.

I'm having trouble with step 3.  My data from steps 1 and 2 is in a List of DupInfo objects.  Here is the class definition.

```
public class DupInfo
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public long Size { get; set; }
        public uint? CheckSum { get; set; }
        public string BaseDirectory { get; set; }
        public DupInfo(FileInfo file, Crc32 crc, int level)
        {
            FullName = file.FullName;
            Size = file.Length;
            CheckSum = crc.ComputeChecksum(File.ReadAllBytes(FullName));
            BaseDirectory = FullName.Substring(0,FullName.NthIndexOf("\\",level));
        }
        public DupInfo(FileInfo file, int level)
        {
            FullName = file.FullName;
            Size = file.Length;
            BaseDirectory = FullName.Substring(0, FullName.NthIndexOf("\\", level));
        }

    }
```

My question is:

1. What is the best way to load data into a Listview object from a custom classs (DupInfo) list?
2. If a Listview isn't the best tool for displaying my duplicate sets, what is the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a DataGrid bound to an `ObservableCollection<DupInfo>`.

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridDupInfoStack.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding items}">

    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<DupInfo> items { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        items = new ObservableCollection<DupInfo>();

        items.Add(new DupInfo() { BaseDirectory = "Directory1", CheckSum = 0xFF, FullName = "Info1", Size = 100 });
        items.Add(new DupInfo() { BaseDirectory = "Directory2", CheckSum = 0xFE, FullName = "Info2", Size = 150 });
        items.Add(new DupInfo() { BaseDirectory = "Directory2", CheckSum = 0xFD, FullName = "Info3", Size = 200 });
        this.DataContext = this;

    }
}
```

And this is your DupInfo class. I've omitted the constructor to deal with it faster.

```
public class DupInfo
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public uint? CheckSum { get; set; }
    public string BaseDirectory { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]

**Update 1:**

We don't have AddRange available but define an extenstion method for that:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void AddRange(this ObservableCollection<DupInfo> value, List<DupInfo> list)
    {
        foreach (var dup in list)
            value.Add(dup);
    }
}
```

This is our new version:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<DupInfo> items { get; set; }

    List<DupInfo> initialList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        items = new ObservableCollection<DupInfo>();
        initialList = new List<DupInfo>();

        initialList.Add(new DupInfo() { BaseDirectory = "Directory1", CheckSum = 0xFF, FullName = "Info1", Size = 100 });
        initialList.Add(new DupInfo() { BaseDirectory = "Directory2", CheckSum = 0xFE, FullName = "Info2", Size = 150 });
        initialList.Add(new DupInfo() { BaseDirectory = "Directory2", CheckSum = 0xFD, FullName = "Info3", Size = 200 });

        items.AddRange(initialList);

        this.DataContext = this;

    }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void AddRange(this ObservableCollection<DupInfo> value, List<DupInfo> list)
    {
        foreach (var dup in list)
            value.Add(dup);
    }
}
```

So we are loading our elements from a list .. we can use an array there or whatever else according to your needs.

But pay attention if you change the object on which our reference points to. In that case, you will have to use a DependencyProperty or implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Your property will look like this:

```
    public  ObservableCollection<DupInfo> items
    {
        get { return ( ObservableCollection<DupInfo>)GetValue(itemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(itemsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for items.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty itemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("items", typeof( ObservableCollection<DupInfo>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

**Update 2:**

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridDupInfoStack.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Full Name" Binding="{Binding FullName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" Binding="{Binding Size}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="CheckSum" Binding="{Binding CheckSum}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="BaseDirectory" Binding="{Binding BaseDirectory}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Mark for deletion">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=ToDelete, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Content="Delete" Click="btnDelete_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{


    public ObservableCollection<DupInfo> items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<DupInfo>)GetValue(itemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(itemsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for items.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty itemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("items", typeof(ObservableCollection<DupInfo>), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));



    List<DupInfo> initialList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        items = new ObservableCollection<DupInfo>();
        initialList = new List<DupInfo>();

        initialList.Add(new DupInfo() { BaseDirectory = "Directory1", CheckSum = 0xFF, FullName = "Info1", Size = 100 });
        initialList.Add(new DupInfo() { BaseDirectory = "Directory2", CheckSum = 0xFE, FullName = "Info2", Size = 150 });
        initialList.Add(new DupInfo() { BaseDirectory = "Directory2", CheckSum = 0xFD, FullName = "Info3", Size = 200 });

        items.AddRange(initialList);

        this.DataContext = this;
    }


    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var dup in items.ToList())
        {
            if (dup.ToDelete)
            {
                items.Remove(dup);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void AddRange(this ObservableCollection<DupInfo> value, List<DupInfo> list)
    {
        foreach (var dup in list)
            value.Add(dup);
    }
}
```

And your updated DupInfo class:

```
public class DupInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _ToDelete;

    public bool ToDelete
    {
        get { return _ToDelete; }
        set
        {
            _ToDelete = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ToDelete"));
        }
    }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public uint? CheckSum { get; set; }
    public string BaseDirectory { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

That's about it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Olaru,  I like that idea.  I'm wondering how to transform my DupInfo list into the "items" object.  Is there an addrange or copyto method that would work with an ObservableCollection?  Or can I set an ItemsSource equal to something.  Should I set items equal to a LINQ query to that transforms the data?

Comment: Actually, after looking at your code more, I think I misunderstood.  It looks like it doesn't require any transformation, but will display the DupInfo fields from the DupInfo objects directly.  Is that correct?  If so, how can I add the entire dupInfos list?  Can I use AddRange() to do that?

Comment: @KalevMaricq DataGrid has a property name AutoGenerateColumns which is by default true. If you keep it like that you won't need other transformations. But if you want to define templates for your columns, set it to false and have a look here http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/ on how to define DataGridTemplateColumn.

Comment: @KalevMaricq Yes, that AddRange extension should do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try going this route.  How do I add checkboxes so the user can indicate which files to delete?

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know what reference I need for ObservableCollection?  It's giving me an error that it can't be found.  Online people mentioned System.Object, which I have, and WindowsBase which isn't in my using statements but is in my project references.

Comment: Nvm, I finally got it.  Added `using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;` to my references.