# How to merge two lists and remove duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, list, join

Given I have two list like the following:

```
var listA = new List<string> { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
var listB = new List<string> { "test2", "test3", "test4" };
```

I want a third list with:

```
var listC = new List<string> { "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"}
```

Is there a way to get this?

Comment: have you googled it? there are too many result about it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest way to form a union of two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505672/simplest-way-to-form-a-union-of-two-lists)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try the [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method.

```
var result = listA.Union(listB).ToList();
```

Union produces the set union of two sequences by using the default equality comparer so the result contains only distinct values from both lists.

Answer (score 2):

```
listA.AddRange(listB).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Concat()` and then `Distinct()` Linq methods

```
listA.Concat(listB).Distinct().ToList();
```