# Matching and Joining Lists by common elements

Tags: c#

The Situation is :
I have a huge number of lists with a fixed size of 3 elements, for a group of four of those lists, there will be 4 unique elements that make up these lists.
Example:

```
Elements = [Object A, Object B, Object C, Object D, Object E, Object F, Object G, Object H]
Lists:
List 1 = {A,B,C}
List 2 = {B,C,D}
List 3 = {C,D,A}
List 4 = {D,A,B}
List 5 = {E,F,G}
List 6 = {F,G,H}
List 7 = {G,H,E}
List 8 = {H,E,F}
```

The output lists should be like this

```
List firstObject = {A,B,C,D}
List secondObject = {E,F,G,H}
```

So, in this example elements [A, B, C, D] made four lists of three elements per list.
Here comes the question: how can I match these four lists to get a single list that Contains [A, B, C, D]

> > Edit:
> > The Actual problem is: I have a list of 2D Lines, and I want to know every 4 lines that make a rectangle.
> > I started with intersecting the lines, and I got a group of lists, each list contains a line that intersects with 2 more lines.
> > Now the goal is to join these lists that have the four edges of the Rectangle.

Comment: You can use `Union` method of IEnumerable, this will avoid duplicates.

Comment: Alternately, you can use the `SelectMany()` and then `Distinct()` as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6948646/14973743)

Comment: I'm confused. I don't see where you're getting "4 unique elements" from. You've listed 8: A through H.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb the data extracted will be four lists, and the unique elements in these four lists are these four elements that i want , did i explain it right?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran The problem is the First list will contain a huge number of these lists of three , did you get what i mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using modular arithmetic and sum will work.  If you divide the index of the item by 4 and sum the 3 values you will be able to group by this number.

```
    class Program
    {
 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> Elements = new List<string>() {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"};
            MyClass[][] lists = {
                                  new MyClass[] {new MyClass() { name = "A", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "B", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "C", value = 0}},
                                  new MyClass[] {new MyClass() { name = "B", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "C", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "D", value = 0}},
                                  new MyClass[] {new MyClass() { name = "C", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "D", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "A", value = 0}},
                                  new MyClass[] {new MyClass() { name = "D", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "A", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "B", value = 0}},
                                  new MyClass[] {new MyClass() { name = "E", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "F", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "G", value = 0}},
                                  new MyClass[] {new MyClass() { name = "F", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "G", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "H", value = 0}},
                                  new MyClass[] {new MyClass() { name = "G", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "H", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "E", value = 0}},
                                  new MyClass[] {new MyClass() { name = "H", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "E", value = 0},new MyClass() { name = "F", value = 0}},
                              };

            var results = lists.Select(x => new { sum = (x.Select(y => Elements.IndexOf(y.name)/4).Sum()), values = x })
                .GroupBy(x => x.sum)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, This may be it, it is still too much advanced for me to understand , but i will try , thank you

Comment: It is really very simple math.  The first four elements of array are index 0,1,2,3 and next are 4,5,6,7.  So dividing by 4 the first four items would be 0 and the next four items would be 1.  Summing any three items of first array will always be 0 while summing any three items of second array will be 3.  The dictionary isn't going to work so I changed to List().

Comment: they are not an array, and they are not sorted

Comment: you can think of it as a pool of lists

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet would be to make use of a [hashset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0):

```
HashSet<Letter> uniqueValues = new HashSet<Letter>();

Letter A = new Letter() { Name = "A" } ;
Letter B = new Letter() { Name = "B" };
Letter C = new Letter() { Name = "C" };
Letter D = new Letter() { Name = "D" };

Letter[] list1 = new Letter[] { A, B, C };
Letter[] list2 = new Letter[] { B, C, D };
Letter[] list3 = new Letter[] { C, D, A };
Letter[] list4 = new Letter[] { D, A, B };

var lists = new Letter[][] { list1, list2, list3, list4 };

foreach (var list in lists)
{
    foreach (var letter in list)
    {
        uniqueValues.Add(letter);
    }
}

Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", uniqueValues));  //  A, B, C, D
```

Hashsets specifically don't record duplicate values, so no matter how many times you add the letter A to your hashset, it'll only appear once. That seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: The objects are not 'char' , they are Lines.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by Lines?

Comment: the Four Elements that are represented by A, B , C , D  - are not 'char' type, they are objects representing a line,  i made the example using these letters to make it simple

Comment: Your question could stand a bit of clarification, in that case.

Comment: i will try to edit it

Comment: Regardless, it should work the same way whether you're using chars, strings or objects. If each letter is a reference to an object then that reference can only be added to the hashset once.

Comment: I've edited my answer to demonstrate.